# Do virtual particles get their mass properties by participating in the Higgs mechanism?

Tags: higgs, virtual-particles

Virtual particles are not bound by the energy-momentum-relationship
$$p_\mu p^\mu=m_0^2c^2$$
as real particles are. They are "off-shell". Does this mean that virtual particles can acquire or lack rest mass? Where does this rest mass come from? Since rest mass in general is believed to be created from massless particles by the Higgs mechanism, I would assume that virtual particles also obtain their changes of rest mass by the Higgs mechanism. In particular, a massless particle (like the photon) might become massive as a virtual particle, and this is because of Higgs?

Or a more specific example: beta decay.
$$d\to u + W^- \to u + \bar{\nu_e} + e^-$$
(hope I wrote this correctly). $W^-$ is a virtual particle, but it has a rest mass of 80 times the neutron/proton. Where does this huge mass/energy come from or why doesn't it matter in the energy balance. I guess it is "borrowed" from the vacuum (time-energy-uncertainty), but what does that mean in relation to the Higgs mechanism that the $W^-$ is subject to?

Or am I mixing up different levels of description (perturbative/non-perturbative) by applying the Higgs concept to virtual particles?

Comment: Virtual particles are a calculational tool. The objects that "gain a mass" are actual matter fields in a Lagragian that exhibits some kind of Higgsing. The presence of "off-shell' propagators is more or less unrelated to the Higgs mechanism, and is just an artefact of the Feynman diagram expansion.